# How to get "Returning Users" graph on Google Analytics Dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics

By default, Google Analytics provide the User graph on the dashboard; **how do I create a copy that reads only the "Returning User"?**

Not sure if I did it right, I'm using the "**Filter > User Type > Contain 'Returning'**"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's one way of doing it: though it only applies to the individual graph you add the filter to.

To apply this restriction to the entire dashboard, use the 'Returning Users' segment — which I believe is built into Analytics (see below).

[image]